# How can I console.log an object, prototype, constructor and a property?

Tags: javascript

I am in this part of youdontknowjs.com and somehow I got confused on identifying an object, prototype, property, etc.

This is the code:

```
function Foo(who) {
    this.me = who;
}
Foo.prototype.identify = function() {
    return "I am "+this.me;
};

var a1 = new Foo("a1");
var a2 = new Foo("a2");

a2.speak = function() {
    alert("Hello, "+this.identify()+'."');
};

a1.constructor === Foo;
a1.constructor === a2.constructor;
a1.__proto__ === Foo.prototype;
a1.__proto__ = a2.__proto__;
```

How can I console.log an object, prototype, constructor and a property?

Comment: Please show us the code where you tried to use `console.log`

Comment: what do you mean by how can I console.log ? you want to call console.log(a1); ?